# Persist BLE connection and access service after closing app

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am working on app with BLE device. All is working fine except the fact that I have problems maintaining the BLE connection after app closure.

I am using Bind Service + Start sticky with foreground service and notification. When I open the app, I call `bindService()`.

The problem is that if I don't call `disconnect()` and `gatt.close()`, the second time I open the app, I cannot access the BLE device because of `onAutoConnectionStatusCb()status =10`
Since I have the service already running, I don't need to call `bindService()` again but in this case I no longer have instance of the service hence my BroadcastReceivers are not called.

How do I get around this?

This is how I start my service:

```
private final Runnable mStartGattRunnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        Intent gattServiceIntent = new Intent(mContext, BluetoothLeService.class);
        gattServiceIntent.putExtra(Consts.DEVICE_ADDRESS, mDeviceAddress);
        gattServiceIntent.setAction(Consts.STARTFOREGROUND_ACTION);

        mContext.startService(gattServiceIntent);

        if (mContext.bindService(gattServiceIntent, mServiceConnection, BIND_AUTO_CREATE))
            CONNECTED = true;
    }
};
```

This is how I get my service instance:

```
    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName componentName, IBinder service) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onServiceConnected()");
        mBluetoothLeService = ((BluetoothLeService.LocalBinder) service).getService();
        if (!mBluetoothLeService.initialize()) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Unable to initialize Bluetooth");

        }
        // Automatically connects to the device upon successful start-up initialization.
        mBluetoothLeService.connect(mDeviceAddress);

        swipeContainer.setRefreshing(true);
    }
```

When I close my app, I don't disconnect or close any connection.

On a second start of the app, if I call `bindService()` again, BLE gets stuck. No way I can access `mBluetoothLeService` again ...

Comment: You'll need to show us some code or explain your architecture better. this isn'tt enough info to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently the issue was with how I was connection to GATT service. I had `false` for auto connect. I changed it and it works now:

```
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
        mBluetoothGatt = device.connectGatt(this, true, mGattCallback, 2);
    else
        mBluetoothGatt = device.connectGatt(this, true, mGattCallback);
```

Comment: You can accept this answer. That will remove this question from the list of unanswered questions.